# Voltage Limitations of a header being used as a voltage selector

Tags: voltage, multiplexer, component-selection, low-voltage

I have an application that takes a reference voltage. These voltages could be considered 'low voltage' as they range from 0 to 1000 V. Below is a reference schematic of what I'm trying to accomplish, demonstrating with two input voltages:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fn02JN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The idea is that I use a selector to select a reference voltage that goes to my output. To accomplish this, I'm planning to use [this male header](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/amphenol-icc-fci/861400102YO2LF/5201747) along with a jumper to jump pins together. With the voltage rating being rated for 1000 volts in this case, and considering the voltages I am working with, would a header work here, or are there other more common methods of creating a selector?

Comment: 1000V is a "low voltage"? Well, OK.. Anyway, what this voltage is going to be used to? Any current draw is expected? If not, what is the point of such a high "reference" voltages?

Comment: At 1000V, you are in the territory where air may start to conduct over short distances. I personally would not use 0.1" header for 1000V for that reason.

Comment: I wouldn't use those headers for 1000V; they don't look well-isolated to me, and the pins are a bit close together. Are you sure you don't mean mV? 1000V is only "low voltage" for very large values of "low".

Comment: Is there going to be some sort of guard so that there is no chance of fingers getting to the voltage selector while the circuit is live?

Comment: IPC minimum electrical clearance for assemblies is 0.00305mm/volt so 3.05mm for 1000V.  You'll need more clearance than a 0.1"/2.54mm header, aside from the very obvious safety issues.  Maybe a socket rated for 1000+ volts and two different plugs that are wired to make the desired connection.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I called it 'low voltage' based on Wikipedia. It claimed that between 50-1500 DC voltage is 'low voltage'. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_voltage#:~:text=In%20electrical%20power%20systems%20low,electric%20arcs%20through%20the%20air.

Answer (score 4):

The datasheet for your part shows that the pin width is 0.63mm (25 mils).  Typically one would over-size the hole on the board by 10 mils (so 35 mils) and then add an annular ring of at least 10 mils.  So the overall pad for each pin is probably a 55 mil circle.

Given that the connector pitch is 100 mils, that leaves 45 mils of pad to pad spacing on the PCB.

[image]

**What Physics says**
The breakdown voltage of air is nominally 3kV per mm.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_breakdown#Liquids

Given the 45 mil spacing calculated above, nominally you won't get an arc until you hit 3.3kV.  But keep in mind that is going to vary with humidity and air pressure.  Additionally, you can start to ionization and corona discharge well below that voltage.

So from a physics standpoint, there is a good chance you won't get an arc at 1000V using 45 mil spacing.  But from a safety standpoint you should probably increase the spacing.

**What the standards say:**
IPC2221B Table 6-1 says that the minimum recommended PCB trace clearance for 1000V is 0.2" if the board is not coated, and 92 mils if its coated.

So according to industry standards 45 mils would not be sufficient clearance for 1000V.

These standards were designed to create safe products.  Its a good idea to follow them.

You might be able to use some sort of cheap PCB mount jumper for this, but just not a 100 mil header.

You could try a reed relay.  Many of them are rated to over 1000V load voltage.
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/reed-relays/964

Another safe option might be a switch rated for at least 1000V.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What if the max voltage was reduced from 1000 down to 500 volts? The table gives it 0.1 inch if uncoated, so that would make the component fit the specification, correct?

Comment: So for 500V the clearance would be 0.1" for an un-coated board.  But we have to be clear about what the clearance actually is, and its not simply the pitch of the connector.  The clearance is the closest distance between two pieces of copper on the board that are not the same net.  If the pitch of the connector pins is 0.1", then the clearance is almost certainly something less than that because the pins themselves (and the pads they mount to) have size that takes away some space.  As I mentioned above, a header with 0.1" pitch is likely to have only 45 mils of clearance.

Answer (score 1):

The standard single pin header is 1A rated. In terms of voltage I haven't seen specifying. If the issue is in regard to the distance between pins, then PCB designer can also assign a couple or more pins as isolation gap is the solution.